# Consuming somthing not halal

Tags: halal-haram

We live in a non muslim country. My parents bought a cake that had gelatin in it. Before eating I checked the ingredients and it said that their was gelatin in it. I asked my mom about it and she said that my dad bought it so it must be halal. The next day we were having the cake and once again I asked my mom if it was halal she asked my dad and he said that he didn't check the ingredients because he didn't think a cake can have gelatin or something like that. I feel horrible about this. Is it my fault that I ate it?If so how do I repent.

Comment: DId you eat it again _after_ you knew it was questionable? Because as-written, i don't see how you "ate it without thinking" since you explicitly asked first and got a positive response that it was fine.

Comment: I know that I did think about it before eating but I should have questioned it more.

Comment: More context is needed. How do you know that the type of gelatin used is haram? Also was this cake purchased from a Muslim bakery or inside a Muslim country? Typically if a Muslim provides you with food then you can assume that it is halal and are not required to question or investigate.

Comment: The place usually sells halal stuff but we are not in a Muslim country.

Answer (score -1):

If you doubt whether gelatin is taken from a plant or from an animal, it is permissible to eat it and there is no need to investigate. But if you know that it is taken from an animal and you are not sure of its Shariah protection, it is not permissible to eat it.

[ref](https://www.sistani.org/persian/qa/0932/)